# Joining to the same table multiple times with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to write a query with that would roughly do:

```
SELECT Challenge.id, Challenge.name, count(AcceptedChallenge.userId) AS attempts, count(a.met) AS met, count(b.active) AS active, count(c.id) AS WHOLE
FROM Challange 
LEFT JOIN AcceptedChallenge ON Challenge.id = AcceptedChallenge.challengeId,
LEFT JOIN AcceptedChallenge AS a ON Challenge.id = a.challengeId
LEFT JOIN AcceptedChallenge AS b ON Challenge.id = b.challengeId
LEFT JOIN AcceptedChallenge AS c ON Challenge.id = c.challengeId
WHERE a.met = true 
AND b.userId = id and b.active = true
AND c.userId = id;
```

Tried multiple versions, including the below:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const ChallengeController = async ({ user: { id } }) => {
  const challenges = await Challenge
    .findAll({
      attributes: {
        include: [[Sequelize.fn('count', Sequelize.col('AcceptedChallenges.userId')), 'attempts'],
        [Sequelize.fn('count', Sequelize.col('a.met')), 'met']]
      },
      include: [{
        model: AcceptedChallenge, attributes: [],
        required: false,
      }, {
        model: AcceptedChallenge, attributes: [],
        as: 'a',
        where: { userId: id, met: true },
        required: false,
      }],
      group: ['Challenge.id']
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log("error:", e);
      throw new HTTP404Error('Challenges not found');
    });
  return challenges;
};
```

It is not recognizing my associations. Please advise. The version here results in: `SequelizeEagerLoadingError: AcceptedChallenge is associated to Challenge using an alias. You've included an alias (a), but it does not match the alias(es) defined in your association (AcceptedChallenges).`

When including the `AcceptedChallenge` model just once, it calculates attempts just fine. I am perplexed as to how I could do the include/JOIN multiple times to get the result, which I need from a single SQL request.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me when the association is repeated, once for each alias needed in your query (example below, but obviously your association may be different).

```
ChallengeController.hasMany(AcceptedChallenge,  {as: 'a', foreignKey: 'challengeId'});
ChallengeController.hasMany(AcceptedChallenge,  {as: 'b', foreignKey: 'challengeId'});
ChallengeController.hasMany(AcceptedChallenge,  {as: 'c', foreignKey: 'challengeId'});
```

Are you doing something similar?